# Why does onLongPress() not return a boolean like all other SimpleOnGestureListener?

Tags: java, android

As the title states. The fact that I can't consume the event is causing a `click` event to occur immediately afterwards. Now I am manually keeping track of whether or not a longpress has occurred when handling a potential click.

Am I missing something here? I mean, I can't even get around this trying to implement the OnGestureListener interface because it expects a void for `onLongPress()`. What are my options?

Comment: How is the fact that it doesn't return a boolean preventing you from implementing it?

Comment: I can implement it, but I can't consume events with it. All the other functions in `SimpleOnGestureListener` return a boolean. I can use that boolean to determine whether or not the event has been consumed. If it was been consumed, I stop any further event handling.

For example, `onFling` returns boolean, so I know not to process a `click` after it. I can't do that with `onLongPress`.

Comment: @TonyLukasavage were you able to find out how to solve this issue or why onLongPress() is void? If so, could you please elaborate a little on it? Thanks, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the onLongPress don't like the onDown these, the return value of the onLongPress is not used to check something, but the return value of onDown is useful to the system, it will help the system to recognitive another events. From the android source code:

```
   mStillDown = true;
   mInLongPress = false;
   if (mIsLongpressEnabled) {
      mHandler.removeMessages(LONG_PRESS);
      mHandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(LONG_PRESS, mCurrentDownEvent.getDownTime() +      TAP_TIMEOUT + LONGPRESS_TIMEOUT);
    }
       mHandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(SHOW_PRESS, mCurrentDownEvent.getDownTime() + TAP_TIMEOUT);
      handled |= mListener.onDown(ev);
```

the onLongPress and ShowPress just tell these situations happend. The return value is not useful for system.

And if you want to implement your design, you can use the varable to check whether the LongPress happened. 
Hope this can help you.